# Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to scrape a page with some news inside.
Here it's an HTML simplified version of what I have :

```
<info id="random_number" class="news"> 
    <div class="author">
        Name of author  
    </div>
    <div class="news-body">
        <blockquote>...<blockquote>
        Here it's the news text
    </div>
</info>
<info id="random_number" class="news"> 
    <div class="author">
        Name of author  
    </div>
    <div class="news-body">
        Here it's the news text
    </div>
</info>
```

I'm getting the author and text body of each news, without the blockquote part.

So I wrote this code :

```
async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await configPage.goto('www.url.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    while (true) {
          await page.reload({ waitUntil: ["networkidle2"] });
          let newsPage = await page.$$("info.news");
          for (var news of newsPage){ // Loop through each element
             let author = await comment.$eval('.author', s => s.textContent.trim());
             let textBody = await comment.$eval('.news-body', s => { s.querySelector('blockquote')?.remove(); return s.textContent.trim(); });

             console.log('Author :'+ author);
             console.log('TextBody :'+ textBody);
          }
          ...Wait some time
    }

}

main();
```

It works well, but sometimes, after a few times, I have this :
Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.

On the line :

```
let author = await comment.$eval('.author', s => s.textContent.trim());
```

How handle this ?

Thank you

Comment: can you please try to add "--disable-dev-shm-usage" on the puppeteer.launch args ? I looked into this issue on github. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1175#issuecomment-369728215

Comment: Thx, ok, I just modify the code and relaunch the script. I will tell you if it become more stable. If it's not, that's ok, but I just want to know how automatically relaunch the script properly if something went wrong.

Comment: It seems a little better, too soon to tell. But when it crash after a few hours, no error, nothing logged anymore, but the process was still there... weird

Comment: Same error : return Promise.reject(new Error(`Protocol error (${method}): Session closed. Most likely the ${this._targetType} has been closed.

Comment: @user2178964 why are you creating a while loop and wait to reload the page and not have your script terminating each time and apply that script to a scheduled job manager like cron? If you want to create a service, that's not how you do it, but then again, you don't need a service for that kind of tasks and even if you do, you should dispose puppeteer and create a new instance every time.

Comment: I want to check a webpage for every change and track it. If the job take 10 seconds each time, I will have a refresh of my scraping each 10 seconds. But sometimes it will take 15 or 17 seconds maybe, I can’t know for sure. I need to be as fast as possible. So don’t want to do a cron job every 30 seconds for example, too slow.

Comment: So the newspage is updated automatically with new headlines a few times in a minute, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, so I need to be instant reactive